# Function to create class

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am trying to create a robust way to define classes "on the fly", but I'm afraid of adding unnecessary overhead to the whole process.

Here is my creation code:

```
function Class(cons,proto) {
    var keys = Object.keys(cons);

    function _class() {
        var i = keys.length;
        while( i-- ) {
            this[ keys[i] ] = arguments[i] || cons[keys[i]];
        }
    }

    if(proto) {
        var f;
        for (f in proto) {
            _class.prototype[f] = proto[ f ];
        }
    }

    return _class
}
```

And here is how I want to use it

```
var car = Class({
                "name": "A car",
                "power": 900
            },
            {
                "honk": function() { alert("honk!") } 
            });


var bmw = new car("BMW", 500);
bmw.honk();     // -> honk!
console.log( bmw.name, bmw.power );     // -> BMW 500

var generic = new car();
generic.honk = function() { alert("custom honk") };
generic.honk();     // -> custom honk!

alert( bmw.honk === car.prototype.honk );   // -> true
alert( generic.honk === car.prototype.honk );       // -> false

console.log( generic.name, generic.power );     // -> A car 900
```

Am I doing anything unnecessary? Do you have any suggestions for improvement?
Please post your opinion

Comment: In javascript, there are no classes, so in a sense it's always on the fly. There are so many ways people have come up with for inheritance and it all boils down to just choosing what you need for a given task. It really depends on what will 1. simplify the rest of your code 2. run efficiently. Basically, it depends on the rest of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing anything unnecessary?

Not that I can see, but you'd need to show us an actual use case for this instead of a demo example :-)

> Do you have any suggestions for improvement?

Looping over `Object.keys(cons)` and using the `i` for anything else but `keys[i]` is errorprone, as [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) does not guarantee any order. It could as well happen that `bmw.power` is `"BMW"` and `bmw.name` is `500`.

Comment: Valid point, the order you declare the properties in an object is not necessary the looping order. Thanks for pointing this out, would have given me headaches later.